# jQuery - checking the result of a function against another

Tags: jquery

My aim is to check a list of links and get the last section of the the URL in the href for each one. Then, I check the URL of the page.

I have a list of pages inside a folder called Projects. Essentially if the URL is projects/somepage and is equal to projects/somepage in the links href, I want to perform an action.

I can loop through the list and return all of the hrefs in the list, and also get the current page URL, yet I can't figure out how to use each of these results to check  if they are the same.

```
projectURL = $("#projects ul li a");

$(function() {

    function checkProjectURL() {     
        $(url).each(function(){ 
            var href = $(this).attr("href");
            var current = href.substr(href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
            //console.log(current);
        }); 
    }

    function checkPageURL() {     
        var url = document.location.href; 
        var currentURL = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
        //console.log(currentURL);

    }

    url = projectURL;

    checkProjectURL();
    checkPageURL();     


});
```

Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return a value from `checkPageURL()` so it can be compared. Then pass this into `checkProjectURL()` so it can perform the comparison.

```
projectURL = $("#projects ul li a");

$(function() {

    function checkProjectURL(url, pageURL) {     
        url.each(function(){ 
            var href = $(this).attr("href");
            var current = href.substr(href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
            //console.log(current);
            if (current == pageURL) {
                // do something
            }
        }); 
    }

    function checkPageURL() {     
        var url = document.location.href; 
        var currentURL = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
        //console.log(currentURL);
        return currentURL;

    }

    checkProjectURL(projectURL, checkPageURL());

});
```